# Is the following proposition a valid characterization of convergence in $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is this true? I think "yes."

**Proposition**. A sequence $z : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers converges iff

1. $|z|$ converges as a sequence of real numbers, and
2. There exists a sequence $\theta : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $z = |z|e^{i\theta}$ such that

   - $\theta$ converges as a sequence of real numbers.

If its false, I'd like to see a counterexample.

If its true, I'd like to see a proof. I'm not really sure how to prove either direction, but maybe something about the continuity of $|*|$ and $\theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false. Let
$$z_n=\frac1n e^{i(-1)^n}.$$
Then the sequence $(-1)^n$ doesn't converge, but $z_n \to 0$. But this is possible only if the limit of $z_n$ is $0$ or $\infty$. Otherwise, the proposition is true. Of course, after adding the condition "mod $2\pi$" for arguments.

Comment: Doesn't that go to zero?

Comment: $(-1)^n$? No. It doesn't converge.

Comment: The proposition as stated doesn't claim that if the sequence $z$ converges, then every possible sequence $\theta$ satsifying $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ converges. The forward direction merely claims that there exists such a $\theta$.

Comment: Every complex number can be written as $|z|e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ defined uniquely up to mod $2\pi$.

Comment: Ah I see. We're bouncing around the origin, and no pattern of adding multiples $2\pi$ to the terms of $\theta$ can change that.

Comment: So I think it can be repaired by adjoining the following words to the end of (1)... "if |z| does not converge to $0$, then"

Comment: @user18921: Yes that repair would make the statement true. Personally I would formulate it as "either $|z(n)|$ converges to$~0$ or there exists a sequence$~\theta$...", but that is merely a matter of taste.

Comment: What do you mean about adding the condition mod 2 for arguments?

Comment: Since your condition 2 starts with "There exists ..." there is no need for "mod $2\pi$".